# ThreeJS: Rotate group of objects with decals around center using pivot object

Tags: html, three.js, rotation, decal

I am trying to rotate a group of objects using a pivot object from the center of the group. Assuming my group of objects are a bunch of car parts like chasis, body, wheels, engine each of which is a 3-D mesh.

Each mesh has a decal that I am adding using the following:

```
var geometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(mesh,worldPosition,...);
var decal= new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)

// Convert decal world transform to mesh local transform

decal.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(mesh.matrixWorld)
mesh.add(decal)
```

To rotate the car around the center of its bounding box I first put all the meshes in a group object

```
var car = new THREE.Object3D();
for (var i=0; i < meshes.length; i++)
{
    car.add(meshes[i])
}
```

then translate the car object and add it to pivot

```
car.position.set(carlength/2,carwidth/2,carheight/2);
var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
pivot.add(car);
scene.add(pivot)
```

To rotate the objects I am applying rotation to pivot object on mouse movement using a similar logic

```
pivot.rotation.x+=1
pivot.rotation.y+=1
pivot.rotation.z+=1
```

Now here's the issue I am facing, the translation I applied to the car object is inherited by the meshes, but the decals stay in the same position. I am unable to understand what would have possibly gone wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [official THREE.js decal example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals)?. It is different from your configuration but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: Yes I did. I still can't figure it out. If I add the decals after translation on the parent object things work out exactly as wanted.

Comment: I can't see any obvious fault in your logic.  Perhaps you can use debugger to inspect exactly what three.js does to the transforms of child objects when your "car" is translated using 'position.set'.